# Large images to base64

Tags: android

I search for this over forum but I not find good solution. I found very similar themes, but not helping.

I have problem when i try to encode large image files to base64.. I try to use lower quality but i have problem with large files again.. i use :

```
public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap,String Ext){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
    if(Ext.equals("png")){
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, baos); 
    }else{
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos); 
    }
    byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
        String temp = null;
        try {
            System.gc();
            temp = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if (Ext.equals("png")) {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 20, baos); 
            } else {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);   
            }
            b = baos.toByteArray();
            temp = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.e("EWN", "Out of memory error catched");
        }
        return temp;        
}
```

Now this work for litle files excelent ( lets say <1 mb) when i use quality lower than 100 (in this example 50 or 20) i get ok with litle large file(maybe 3 mb ) but this is not good solution because i still have problem with size 10 mb for example...Program just break..

I was think to convert in chunks ,but this not work for me...

Thank you for answer.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the `String temp` afterwards? If you're planning to write it somewhere, you could use a streaming base64 encoder. For example [Base64OutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64OutputStream.html)

Comment: I need to send it with ksoap2 to webservice

Comment: I don't know `ksoap2`. Does it support streaming file attachments? Please post the working code that is able to post small images successfully.

Comment: @taoufik thanx for answer is helping , I work on new solution but your advice was I need.

Comment: @Frink : Could you help with the approach you used for resolving this issue. I am also using KSOAP2 and finding it difficult to upload large images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the first question would be is there an alternative to base64 encoding the image, what are you using it for? are you then uploading it somewhere or putting it into a database?

does it need to be stored as a string ? Loading such a large image is dangerous, I would personally deal with it using streams instead of loading the entire thing directly.

Apache commons has a commons-codec library which is availible here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/

and it should be simple enough to port:

org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64OutputStream
and 
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64InputStream

into your app. This should allow you to first dump your data in chunks to disk and then read in smaller blocks as you use it for whatever purpose you need to.

Comment: Thax for answer i use Your and @taoufik answer to get new solution,they give me different view of "situation" :)